# Constant expression with custom object

Tags: c++, templates, constant-expression

I'm trying to use an instant of a custom class as a template parameter.

```
class X {
public:
  X() {};
};

template <class Foo, Foo foo>
struct Bar {

};
const X x;
Bar<X, x> foo;
```

The compiler states that `x` cannot appear in a constant expression. Why that? There is everything given to construct that object at compile time.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't do it. Standard 14.1 says:

> **4** A non-type template-parameter shall have one of the following (optionally cv-qualified) types:
>   — integral or enumeration type,
>   — pointer to object or pointer to function,
>   — reference to object or reference to function,
>   — pointer to member.
>   **5** [ Note: other types are disallowed either explicitly below or implicitly by the rules governing the form of *template-arguments*
>   (14.3). —end note ] The top-level cv-qualifiers on the template-parameter are ignored when determining its
>   type.

Comment: Which *are* a lot of options after all. Any POD (excluding floating-point values and dynamic pointers) can be translated into a template, it just can't be converted automatically by the compiler.

Comment: In C++0x we are finally allowed to pass class types as arguments, as long as they have a constexpr conversion function to integral or enum types.

Answer (score 0):

As others have pointed out you can't do it. So long as you are not playing  meta-programming games, the normal way to pass an actual instance of a class is in the constructor:

```
template <class Foo>
struct Bar {
    Bar( const Foo & f ) {
      ...
    }
};
```

Answer (score -1):

Template parameters can be types, or integral constants.  `X` is a type, but `x` is not.  You also can't use constant floating point values.